# ASP.net MVC 3 website initial page load get progressively slower

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

We have a portal website built with MVC 3 which talks to a WCF service. After an iisreset of the portal, logins are instantaneous, however after an hour or two the loading of the first page takes a lot longer (even the actual login page is slow to load). The WCF service still responds quickly so it isn't that.

Has anyone heard of this before? I know it is a very general question which no detail of the portal architecture but I am looking for pointers on where to look.

TIA

Comment: Is that the only website running in the app pool?  can you reproduce the behavior locally?  If so you can profile it to figure out where it is going slow.  You could put some logging in to "stopwatch" time the key sections of code.. so you could tell if your code is running slower over time or if IIS is getting slower over time.

Answer (score 0):

- Is the memory usage going up?
- Is the CPU going up?

I would suggest performance profiling the app (Ants profiler, dotTrace) to see where the time is lost. Otherwise it's just guessing.